# How to "reset" fragment state ANDROID

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I want to use a `reset` button on my `fragment`. This button should reset that fragment to the initial state. Is it possible? Or I have to restore every widget state one by one? Thanks.

Comment: `remove(fragment).commitNow()` and `add(fragment).commitNow()`

Comment: What is the `fragment` object that I have to add?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I found is:
`getFragmentManager()
.beginTransaction()
.detach(fragment)
.attach(fragment)
.commit();`

To `recreate` the view.

Comment: That doesn't recreate the fragment, but it does recreate its view.